# C4D image problems

Tags: video, editing, cinema4d

I have added a custom image from the internet to a cylinder, and it shows up as normal when editing. However when I preview the render or render it out the image completely disappears and the cylinder goes blank, how do I fix this?

Comment: Can you explain how you added the image to the cylinder? Did you make a custom material? Maybe provide screenshots. Also [this previous question](http://video.stackexchange.com/q/7180/2178) might be relevant.